# Cauchy's integral formula proof

Tags: complex-analysis

When proving Cauchy's integral formula we define:

$$
G(z)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0},  \text{     } z\neq z_0\\
f'(z_0), \text{     }  z=z_0
\end{cases}
$$

To continue we have to show that $G(z)$ is analytic except to $z_0$.

So in the first case it is as a quotient of to analytic functions. and in the second it is continuous as it is differentiable at $z_0$

So we overall showed that $G(z)$ is continuous everywhere in $D$ and nalytic except to $z_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is the (open) domain of $f$ and if $z_0 \in D$, then $G$ is analytic on $D \setminus \{z_0\}$ and continuous on $D$.